# Node not running on linux shared server due to outdated libraries. How to update?

Tags: node.js, linux

I installed node.js on godaddy linux server as per the instructions given in:
https://ferugi.com/blog/nodejs-on-godaddy-shared-cpanel/

When I run the command: `node --version`, I get the errors:

```
    node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.5' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by node)
```

While it seems that my libraries are outdated, I don't know how to update the libraries on a linux shared server. `apt` does not work. Any solution for this?

Comment: Does [this topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1316816/node-usr-lib64-libstdc-so-6version-glibcxx-3-4-14-glibcxx-3-4-18-cxxabi-1) answer your question?

Comment: I tried. But it is not working. Same error. Node v17.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I learned that libc version is strongly tied with the distribution version. It's not possible to update libc along. Updating the distribution is too complicated, I suggest you download a lower version nodejs binary to be compatible with your OS version.